# YQL request and javascript : displaying everything

Tags: javascript, html, dom, yql

For a project, i need to get the dome of some websites and parse it. I find a solution with YQL. The request seems to work well on this site.
https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

But when i use it on my local website with the following javascript :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>BabylonJS - HexaGrid</title>
 <style>
  body, html { 
   margin:0; 
   padding: 0; 
   border: 0; 
   overflow: hidden; 
   width: 100%; 
   height: 100%; 
  }

  canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
  
  #vr {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   padding: 10px 15px;
   border: 2px solid #ddd;
   background: #4587ea;
   color: #fff;
   transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  
  #vr:hover {
   transition: all 0.3s;
   background: #449fff;
   cursor: pointer;
  } 
 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var url = 'https://www.brainpickings.org/2016/06/09/strange-trees/';
 $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
                "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
                encodeURIComponent(url)+
                "%22&format=json'&callback=?", function(data){
          // if there is data, filter it and render it out
          if(data.results[0]){
            var test = data.results[0];
     alert(test);
          } else {
            var errormsg = "<p>Error: can't load the page.</p>";
            alert(errormsg);
          }
      });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It only display a part of the request. I don't really what went wrong, if it's because the yql request is big and is not finish or i lack some knowledge for getting what remain.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using but missing the jQuery library, and doesn't wait for the document to be ready. Here is the code fixed and working:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>BabylonJS - HexaGrid</title>
    <style>
        body,
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        #vr {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            border: 2px solid #ddd;
            background: #4587ea;
            color: #fff;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }
        
        #vr:hover {
            transition: all 0.3s;
            background: #449fff;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var url = 'https://www.brainpickings.org/2016/06/09/strange-trees/';
     $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
                    "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
                    encodeURIComponent(url)+
                    "%22&format=json'&callback=?", function(data){
              // if there is data, filter it and render it out
              if(data.results[0]){
                var test = data.results[0];
         alert(test);
              } else {
                var errormsg = "<p>Error: can't load the page.</p>";
                alert(errormsg);
              }
          });
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i did add the line with the jquery but forgot to put it in the snippet. But I totally forgot the $(document).ready. Been a while since i did js. I tried it, but i still have the same mistakes. The data.results[0] only retrieve the DOM till "Susan Sontag on Storytelling, What It Means to Be a Moral Human Being, and Her Advice to Writers</a></h5><div class="c".

Comment: If you do `console.log(data.results)` it displays the source code for the entire page from <body> to </body> (including everything past the article on Susan Sontag). It is a matter of getting what you want from data.results[0].

Comment: Oh i didn't see that i could extend what the console.log was displaying. It works, thanks a lot.